# NullPointerException: null when trying to use jdbcTemplete

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am trying for 2 days to solve my problem and understand where I was wrong.
I am trying to use the TodoService to show items on-grid and to add data into my SQL.
but I get Error:

I am just typing in the 4 fields in the todoview and i click the save(הוסף) Button.
I am guessing my problem with the Service. but I don't get what.
people tried to help me but nothing seems to work.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.packagename.ui.views.TodoView.saveTodo(TodoView.java:111) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.packagename.ui.views.TodoView.onComponentEvent(TodoView.java:127) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:378) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:359) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:359) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:301) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:87) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:246) ~[flow-server-2.0.14.jar:2.0.14]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95) ~[vaadin-spring-12.0.6.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar:9.0.22]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

**TodoService.java**

```
@Component
public class TodoService {
@Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public List<Todo> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT ID, TaskStatus, dudate,subject FROM todo",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Todo(rs.getLong("ID"),
                        rs.getLong("UserID"), rs.getLong("descriptionID"),rs.getString("taskstatus")));
    }

    public void update(Todo todo) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO todo (TaskStatus,dudate,subject,CustomerID) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",todo.getTaskStatus(),todo.getDudate(),todo.getSubject(),todo.getCustomerID());


    }

}
```

Todo.java

```
public class Todo {
    private  long userID;
    private String taskstatus;
    private long ID;
    private long customerID;
    private long descriptionID;
    private String taskStatus;
    private String Subject;
    private LocalDate Dudate;

    public Todo() // Def Ctor
    {

    }

 public Todo (String taskstatus,LocalDate dudate,String subject,long customerid){

     this.customerID= customerid;
     this.Subject = subject;
     this.Dudate = dudate;
     this.taskstatus = taskstatus;
 }
    public Todo(long id, long customerid, long descriptionid, String task) { // Ctor all
        this.ID=id;
        this.customerID=customerid;
        this.descriptionID=descriptionid;
        this.taskStatus=task;

    }

    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public long getDescriptionID() {
        return descriptionID;
    }

    public void setDescriptionID(long descriptionID) {
        this.descriptionID = descriptionID;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return taskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.Subject = subject;
    }

    public LocalDate getDudate() {
        return Dudate;
    }

    public void setDudate(LocalDate dudate) {
        this.Dudate = dudate;
    }

    public long getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(long customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }
}
```

TodoView.java

```
package com.packagename.ui.views;

@Route(value = NAV,layout = MainView.class)
public class TodoView extends Composite<Div> {
    public static final String NAV = "todo";
    public Todo todo = new Todo();
    private Grid<Todo> todogrid = new Grid<>(Todo.class);
    private Binder<Todo> binder = new Binder<>(Todo.class);
    @Autowired
    @SuppressWarnings( "SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")
    private TodoService service ;

    private  Button addButton = new Button("Save", //   } catch (ValidationException ex) {
            //     ex.printStackTrace();
            this::onComponentEvent);

    public TodoView(){

        //Layouts//
        HorizontalLayout todofields = new HorizontalLayout();
        VerticalLayout todoList = new VerticalLayout();
        HorizontalLayout subjects = new HorizontalLayout();
        todogrid.addThemeNames("no-border","no-row-borders","row-strips");
        GridMultiSelectionModel<Todo> selectionModel = (GridMultiSelectionModel<Todo>) todogrid
                .setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);
        selectionModel.selectAll();


        //Layouts//



        //Fields//
        ComboBox<String> taskstatus = new ComboBox<>("TaskStatus:");
        taskstatus.setItems("Completed","OnProgress","Cancelled");
        TextField subject = new TextField();
        subject.setLabel("נושא:");
        TextField customerid = new TextField();
        customerid.setLabel("שם הלקוח:");
        DatePicker dudate = new DatePicker();
        dudate.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        dudate.setLabel("תאריך סיום:");
        //Binder//
        binder.forField(subject).bind(Todo::getSubject,Todo::setSubject);
        binder.forField(dudate).bind(Todo::getDudate,Todo::setDudate);
        binder.forField(taskstatus).bind(Todo::getTaskStatus,Todo::setTaskStatus);
        binder.forField(customerid).withConverter(new StringToLongConverter(""))
                .bind(Todo::getCustomerID,Todo::setCustomerID);
        //Binder//


        addButton.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
        addButton.setThemeName("primary");


        //Fields//






        todofields.add(subject,customerid,dudate,taskstatus,addButton);
        todofields.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);
        todoList.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);
        todofields.getElement().getStyle().set("margin-left","auto");
        getContent().add(todofields,subjects,todoList,todogrid);
        Direction.set(Direction.RTL);

    }

    private void saveTodo() {

        service.update(todo);
    }

    private void updateGrid() {
        List<Todo> todo = service.findAll();

        todogrid.setItems(todo);
    }

    private void onComponentEvent(ClickEvent<Button> e) {
        try {
            binder.writeBean(todo);
            System.out.println(todo.getCustomerID());
            System.out.println(todo.getTaskStatus());
            System.out.println(todo.getDudate());
            System.out.println(todo.getSubject());
            saveTodo();
            updateGrid();
            binder.readBean(new Todo());
            //   } catch (ValidationException ex) {
            //     ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ValidationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the stack trace, it appears that service is probably null. Have you checked to see if it's being properly autowired?

Comment: @mcarlin you cant see that by my code? how can i check that ?

Comment: My guess is at runtime that it's not really being populated and `service` is null. What do the warnings say that you're supressing with `@SuppressWarnings( "SpringJavaAutowiredMembersInspection")`?

Comment: Is this a spring boot app or a WAR? If it's spring boot, are you using the [vaadin spring plugin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-spring) to allow for dependency injection?

Comment: this is null private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; You need to wire this.

Comment: @mcarlin
warrning:autowired members must be defined in valid spring bean (@component @service)

and its spring boot app- i add the spring plugin, not seems to work to.

Comment: @Gagan I did wire, can't you see that in my code?

Comment: when you debug, does it show jdbctemplate = null ?, try  @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Comment: @Snirbenyosf What does your package structure look like? `However, scanning only occurs inside the Spring Boot application class package, that is the package in which the @SpringBootApplication class resides. If your application contains route classes in packages that are not scanned by default, you have two options: move them to the package (or subpackage) in which the @SpringBootApplication application class resides...` from [Vaadin spring routing tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-routing.html)

Comment: @Gagan I disagree that the issue lies with the `jdbcTemplate`. The top of stack trace doesn't show it entering the context of the `TodoService`'s `update()` method:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.packagename.ui.views.TodoView.saveTodo(TodoView.java:111) ~[classes/:na]`

Comment: @mcarlin
`@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}`

Comment: @Snirbenyosf Can you add your pom/gradle configuration?

Comment: @mcarlin [link](https://justpaste.it/76r8o)

Comment: @Snirbenyosf Can you provide what your application directory structure looks like? It might be related to where spring is searching for annotations.

Comment: Agree with @mcarlin, please update all three code snippets to include package name and imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that the Route annotation is not managed by Spring Boot. Therefore, any @Autowired will not work. 
Have you tried to add the @SpringComponent annotation (https://vaadin.com/api/vaadin-spring/12.0.6/com/vaadin/flow/spring/annotation/SpringComponent.html)?

Comment: In a Vaadin Spring application, the routes are initialized such that Spring can inject the dependencies. While they are not Spring beans, autowiring can be used without an additional annotation. https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your service probably resides in a package that is not scanned by spring so spring is unaware of any injectable bean, it doesn't find any. What you need to do is tell Spring where to look for components, or move your `Application` class some packages up (it automatically scans all packages below it IIRC).

You can define where spring must look for spring-components in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in your `Application` class: provide a list of packages that have spring components in them in the attribute `scanBasePackages`.

As soon as Spring is aware of your `TodoService`, it will successfully inject it into your view.

Edit: The SQL Query for `TodoService::findAll` also seems odd, you select the columns `ID, TaskStatus, dudate, subject` but from the resultset you read the values `ID, UserID, descriptionID, taskstatus`. This is not what caused your current error but will cause another error once you resolved your current one.